# syntax error, unexpected '{' at token "{"

Tags: syntax

So somewhere in this pile of code I am getting the above error (as seen in title) and I have spent a great deal of time trying to figure out why.

```
vec4 calcPointLight(PointLight pointLight, vec3 normal);
 {
  vec3 lightDirection = worldPos0 - pointLight.position;
  float distanceToPoint = length(lightDirection);
  lightDirection = normalize(lightDirection);

  vec4 color = calcLight(pointLight.base, lightDirection, normal);

  float attenuation = pointLight.atten.constant +
                      pointLight.atten.linear * distanceToPoint +
                      pointLight.atten.exponent * distanceToPoint *  distanceToPoint +
                      0.0001;
```

return color / attenuation;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the semicolon at the end of the first line.

Side note: you should really mention what language you're working with at the very least.